# Execute Multiline sybase statement with java.sql.Statement

Tags: java, sql, sybase, rowcount

How can I both set rowcount and then execute a query in a Statement.executeQuery() function?

note I don't want to use Statement.setMaxRows() to do this

Comment: What do you mean by rowcount - @@rowcount is set by the command and not by the programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sybase ASE 12.5.3, you need to use "set rowcount #" and then select the entries. 
For higher versions you can simply use the following

```
--Get top 10 rows.
select top 10 * from TAB_A order by my_col asc
```

Check your Sybase ASE version by giving

```
select @@version
```

If your version is not 12.5.4 or above, I suggest upgrading to 12.5.4. (You will just have to install an EBF)